# Elastich search - ICU Collation Keyword Field - Norwegian language - aa elastich search consider as å when sorting

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search elasticsearch:6.8.4 on fos in Symfony 4.4 by **friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.0"**

I am facing an issue with sort field with config in fos_elastica.yaml. My config like:

```
 user_first_name_sort: {type: icu_collation_keyword, language: nb, index: true}
```

This work fine for **Norwegian language** as expected. But, word **aa** elastich search consider as **å** when sorting. Example:
[image]

How can i ignore implictly transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia on the Norwegian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet#History)

> The letter Å (HTML &aring;) was introduced in Norwegian in 1917,
> replacing Aa or aa.
> [...]
> Family names may not follow modern orthography, and as such retain the digraph aa where å would be used today.

and more specifically on the subject of collation

> Aa is treated like Å in alphabetical sorting, not like two adjacent
> letters A, meaning that while a is the first letter of the alphabet,
> aa is the last.

Your sort order is correct.

Comment: Following my investigation, why's not "AE OE" treated like "AA", they are still be considered as Ae and Oe not æ and ø ?

Comment: Probably because `å` is an official replacement for `aa` but `ae` for `æ` and `oe` for `ø` are only accepted for international spellings . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98 for example : In other languages that do not have the letter as part of the regular alphabet, or in limited character sets such as ASCII, ø may correctly be replaced with the digraph "oe" [...]